# Angular2 basic authenfification http request

Tags: angular, tomcat

I am making a http request with basic authentification but it is not working. If I use auth within my proxy-conf.json then it is working but I need to pass the user and pw to the request. How can I auth via http request or what can I do?

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/rest/*": {
    "target": "http://mania:8080/com.test.test.server",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
  "auth": "username:password"
  }
}
```

**HTTP REQEUST**

```
getKeyID(){


    let url="/rest/v4/repository/test/test/REST/Master:jobs";

    return this.http.post(url, this.getPutHeaders()).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                 data => {
                   console.log(data.id);
                   localStorage.setItem('key', data.id.toString())

                 },
                 err => console.log(err)
              );
  }


  private getPutHeaders(){
      let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json'});
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user:pw'));
      return new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers

      });
  }
```

Serverside I using Tomcat.

**Solution:**
I need to change the mediatype to "Content-Type".

Comment: What error do you have ? Is it a CORS problem ? Request not sent ?

Comment: An alert window is displaying see above?

Comment: Okay, you have to disable basic auth in your backend server. Are you using Spring security ?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to set my username and password. Well, I can not see any request. I am not getting errors or something like that. I am not using Spring security

Comment: ok, I found the solution. See above.